# OpenCV on Android Studio

Tags: opencv, android-gradle-plugin, android

I am trying to use OpenCV on Android Studio, I followed [this site](http://jeanvitor.com/opencv-3-2-android-studio/) step by step and when I reached the "Testing some Android code" section, I copied the code to my Android Studio with the changes that required for my MainActivity and I am trying to build the apk file to install the application on my phone. I can't do this because I have a lot of errors.

These are the errors:

[image]

I am new to Android developing.

Comment: One approach is to take each error and search for it, using a search engine, together with the keyword "Android". That should help you fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Make sure you have Android SDK up to date, with NDK installed

**2.** Download latest OpenCV SDK for Android from OpenCV.org and decompress the zip file.

**3.** Create a new Android Studio project

- Check Include C++ Support
- Choose empty Activity
- In C++ Support, you can check -fexceptions and -frtti

**4.** Import OpenCV library module

- New -> Import Module
- Choose the YOUR_OPENCV_SDK/sdk/java folder
- Unckeck replace jar, unckeck replace lib, unckeck create gradle-style

**5.** Set the OpenCV library module up to fit your SDK

Edit openCVLibrary/build.gradle to match your app/build.gradle e.g:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 27
}
```

**6.** Add OpenCV module dependency in your app module

File -> Project structure -> Module app -> Dependencies tab -> New module dependency -> choose OpenCV library module

**7.** Make a **jni** folder by right clicking on **app/src/main** and click **change folder** box after that rename folder fron **jni** to **jniLibs**

**8.** Copy all files from your opencv directory ***YOUR_OPENCV_SDK/sdk/native/libs*** that you have downloaded and paste them in **jniLibs** folder

**9.** Set the app build.gradle

- Add abiFilters

  ```
  externalNativeBuild {
  cmake {
      cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
      abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
     }
  }
  ```

**10.** Configure the CMakeLists.txt file

- After the cmake_minimum_required, add

  ```
  include_directories(YOUR_OPENCV_SDK/sdk/native/jni/include)
  add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
  set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)
  ```

***Every thing is done.***

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this solves your problem then please marked it as answer.